# Angular 5 Multiple Comma Separated HttpParams

Tags: angular, angular5

I have set of data, users can filter the data by status. Status is committed, uncommitted, completed and failed.

To filter the data i send a get request to the backend api that looks something like this.

```
/api/data/?status=uncommited,commmitted
```

The above call will only bring back data that is either uncommited or committed.

I am having trouble implementing this as the network tab shows my request like the following:

```
/api/data/?status=uncommited&status=commmitted
```

Can you see how the above has two "status" rather than 1 which is comma separated.

**data.service.ts**

```
get(params = null) {

    let endpoint = "<removed>/api/v1/jobs"

    let filters = new HttpParams({fromObject: params});

    return this.apiService.get(endpoint, filters);

}
```

**data.component.ts**

```
this.filterForm = this.fb.group({
            status: [],

        });

       this.filterForm.valueChanges.subscribe((res) => {

            this.filters = _.pickBy(res, _.identity);

            let params = this.filters;

            this.dataService.get(params).subscribe((res) => {
                this.dataSource = res.data;
            });
        });
```

**data.component.html**

```
form fxLayout="row" [formGroup]="filterForm" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" fxLayoutGap="10px" (change)="filter()">

            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-select placeholder="Status" formControlName="status" multiple>
                    <mat-option value="any">Any</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="completed">Completed</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="uncommitted">Uncommited</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="committed">Commited</mat-option>

                    <mat-option value="failed">Failed</mat-option>

                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: you have not severals params, just only one. I supouse you want to say let params = this.filters.join(',') ?

Comment: I have multiple params im just giving a strict view of the code, to solve a specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `%2C` to separate the multiple values passed on the `status` parameter. Then is the server-side which performs an URL decoding to get the list of parameters. `%2C` is the url-encoded value of `,`

Using this approach, Angular will treat it as a single parameter and your call would like:
`/api/data/?status=uncommited%2Ccommmitted`.

**Edited**

```
let status = ['uncommited', 'commmitted']
let filters = new HttpParams();
filters = filters.append('status', status.join(', ');
// Append here as much params as needed
this.apiService.get(endpoint, { params: filters });
```

Comment: I understand that but im asking How? I assume that if i passed the HttpParams an array it would do this automatically for me.

Comment: You may use the `append` method then. It accepts a string as parameter and can be combined with the array `join`. I am going to update my answer.

Comment: I will wait for your updated answer, bare in mind i will have another params not jsut status.

Comment: The append method can be called multiple times in order to add the rest of the params.

Comment: What is "Params"? and status.join. I dont tihnk the method works that way.

Comment: The "Params" was used as example, I've updated the code using your naming convention to make it clear. When calling the apiService it passes the endpoint and the filters as an object.
The join method converts your status array into a string separated by `, `. You may use `%2C `  in case comma doesn't work.